# Hugo's equivalent of PHP's strpos()

Tags: go, hugo

So, I want to break `.Content` up to fit in different nav-tabs. If there's a better pattern to accomplish, please let me know.

So, in my `/content/shop/product-name/index.md` front matter contains:

```
# summary
summary: "This is the **product's** summary which will render markdown"
---
This is the first line of the full description of the product. This section of the ./index.md
page is referenced in the `single.html` file as `.Content`.|^^|This is the next part of the
.Content that I want to throw into a different nav-tab.
```

Then in `/layouts/shop/single.html`:

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
       {{ .Params.summary }}
     </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav class="product-info-tabs wc-tabs mt-5 mb-5">
          <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab"
              aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Description</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab"
              aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Additional Information</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab"
              aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Reviews</a>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
            {{ .Content }}
          </div>
...
```

In days gone past, in PHP, I could use `strpos(.Content, '|^^|')` and then `substr(.Content, 0, (strpos(.Content, '|^^|'))` to get a section of text. You could also throw the string into an array with a user configured delimiter `split('|^^|', .Content)`.

So, back in Hugo, within `.Content` I could have something like:

```
This is the content. This is the last line before being split.|^^|This is the next line, that would be in array[1] or the next indexed substr.
```

I'm trying to get these two sections of `.Content` into different tabs of the `single.html` page. Each product `.Content` will obviously be different so I can't really have a consistent count to use Hugo's `substr()`.

The problem that I see with using the front matter, is, although it is markdown rendered, it can't span multiple lines. I know I could use `\n` for new lines, but that defeats the benefits of markdown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could probably just do:

```
{{ replace .Content "|^^|" "</div><div class='tab-pane fade show'>" | safeHTML}}
```

Which would turn

```
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        This is the content. This is the last line before being split.|^^|This is the next line, that would be in array[1] or the next indexed substr.
      </div>
```

into

```
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        This is the content. This is the last line before being split.
      </div>
      <div class='tab-pane fade show'>
        This is the next line, that would be in array[1] or the next indexed substr.
      </div>
```

Comment: That works, but what if the replace is a lot more code than that? Or, as I have, three panes. Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: For three panes it already works.  But honestly, at a certain point I'd start using yaml instead of markdown for the front matter and then you can just iterate over a list.